# How to block\allow specific ip in my Exit-relay Tor

Tags: exit-relays

I'd like to know if there is a way I can block / allow specific ip's address
to access my Exit-relay.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop arbitrary client IP addresses from building circuits that involve your exit node. How would your exit even know what clients are using it? It doesn't know.

You can configure your exit node to not connect **out** to specific IP addresses and ports by using the `ExitPolicy` torrc options.